# 3DS XL Having trouble accessing Eshop

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have issues accessing Nintendo EShop, once i try it gives error code 022-2502 and says "This Nintendo Network ID cannot be used because its region setting does not match the setting of this system" I've scoured youtube but only one person has details but i have to wipe my system clean.

Comment: Where did you buy your Nintendo console? Are you currently in a different country? Did you change your region settings?

Comment: Hello, i bought it from Gamestop like most people do, i changed region because i once realized whilst playing that my console was already set to live in Anguilla so i changed it to United States and that's when this problem occurred. (i forgot to mention its not new, i bought it 5 years ago just about)

Comment: Then setting it back to Anguilla should work.

Comment: It does work, but for Anguilla there's only 6 things in the Eshop, and the thing i was looking for was not one. but i do not think there's  an option to change location for some reason  so thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching back to your initial region helped your current case, but I still suggest updating the information if it's incorrect (I'm not entirely sure if you're actually located in the US or on Anguilla), as this might prevent more/other problems in the future.

Guides to do so are available on nintendo.com:

- for your [Nintendo Account Profile](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15987), and
- for the [Nintendo Network ID](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1085) you might have created when getting your console.

Both guides mention that what might be preventing you from changing your region is still having credit on your account. [Spending it should fix that problem](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/25847).

Comment: Thanks again, but where do i see which email is linked to my Nintendo account?, its an old account and i believe  i might have changed emails since then..

Comment: You can try finding it following the instructions [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15991/~/forgot-nintendo-account-sign-in-info-%28email-address%2C-password%2C-sign-in-id%29#DT:t1-q1a1EP:t1-q1a1-c).